Fix for incorrect pixel size post transformation
I have a .tif in WGS 84 and one in EPSG 32632.
EPSG has a resolution of 10m (so the pixel sizes are 10).
When I convert WGS 84 into the EPSG 32632 CRS, even after specifying that the new resolution should be 10, the resulting pixel size is ~9.999.

Is there a way to ensure that the resulting pixel size after CRS transformation is exactly 10m?

Allowing for floating point accuracy that is 10m

Is there a setting where I can define this argument?

When reprojecting from WGS84 geographic to any projected coordinate system, the data has been tortured to the point that a 1mm pixel size difference is the least of your problems.

@Vince would you mind expanding upon that statement? What other problems would I be encountering?

if you want it to read "10" then use round()

@IanTurton would this be using Python then? I don't know QGIS that well and am somewhat new to Rasterio in Python.

We are saying that it doesn't matter as the value is so close to 10 as to be indistinguishable in the real world. You don't have a problem

Please add information from the original: a) size of the image in pixels b) pixel size c) corner coordinates. Gdalinfo shows them all.

@user30184 I will update these coordinates. Where can I access gdalinfo in QGIS?

@IanTurton Ultimately, it causes a problem for me. I plan on converting the transformed .tif file into a .gpkg and combining it's attribute table with an attribute table of another .gpkg that is already in the desired (32632) crs. As it currently stands, the minimal inaccuracy is resulting in a significant number of extra pixels.

Then you need to make sure all your input data is in the same projection and resolution before you start any processing. Otherwise there is no chance of your rasters lining up.

Gdalinfo is a command line utility but you can find pixel size, dimensions, and extent also with QGIS, from the layer properties.
